# Using GWT defferred binding to replace non-gwt classes with gwt classes

Tags: java, xml, gwt, dom, w3c

I have a *very simple* problem that I was hoping I can solve with GWT's deffered binding.

I have a large amount of code that was programmed to the org.w3c.dom.* interfaces. I don't want to change this code so I was hoping that I could swap out these classes at compile time.

Something like this (even though it doesn't work):

```
<replace-with class="com.google.gwt.dom.client.Document">
    <when-type-is class="org.w3c.dom.Document"/>
  </replace-with>
```

From my understanding I think the problem here is that both of my classes need to implement the same interface. Which, correct me if I am wrong, leaves me in a situation where I will need to rework a lot of things to make this do what I need.

I was hoping there was a simpler solution?

Thanks,

Casey

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the `<super-source>` directive (see **Overriding one package implementation with another** in the [Organize Projects](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects?hl=en) section of the Dev Guide).

Comment: Sweet. Exactly what I was looking for. Skimmed over the guide a few times today and that never stuck out. Thank you!

Comment: @CaseyJordan Did you copy the sources of `com.google.gwt.xml.XML` into the `<supersourcefolder>/org/w3c/dom` or did you manage to tell the compiler to reuse `com.google.gwt.xml.XML`?

Comment: I wanted more control over the actual DOM implementation so I ended up grabbing the w3c dom interfaces as well as the gwt.xml code and refactoring everything to be under org.w3c.dom.*. This works pretty well.